# How to change the return type of this utility function so that it returns individual values

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting the return type in form of array for example

```
name : ["Orange Juice"]
cost : [20]
```

How to remove arrays and double quotes

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wcy57qt/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wcy57qt/8/):

```
console.log('name : '+JSON.stringify((findbyId('1247').name[0])).replace(/\"/g,""));
console.log('cost : '+JSON.stringify(findbyId('1247').cost[0]));
```

Comment: Glad to know. Welcome...:)!

Answer (score 0):

[.value()](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html#method-r-value) in the jsonQ library you are using returns an array. It looks like you would instead want to use a different return method, like [.firsElm()](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html#method-r-firstElm)

```
var resultObj = {name : name.firstElm(), cost : cost.firstElm(), image : image.firstElm() } ;
```

and then (using regex from other answer)

```
id1247 = findbyId('1247');
console.log('name : ' + JSON.stringify(id1247.name).replace(/\"/g,""));
console.log('cost : '+id1247.cost));
```